# Use Git to restore a copy of some old files while keeping their latest version

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a few files (let's say `file1` and `file2`) that I want to restore a copy of from an old commit. But I would also like to keep their latest version, because the old and new versions ended up doing two different and useful things. More precisely I want to move from the following situation:

```
project/
  |- file1  (latest version)
  |- file2  (latest version)
```

To the following situation:

```
project/
  |- new/
    |- file1  (latest version)
    |- file2  (latest version)
  |- old/
    |- file1  (old version)
    |- file2  (old version)
```

How can I achieve this with Git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every *commit* stores a full and complete snapshot of every file—or rather, every file that's in that particular commit.  Once a commit is made, it can never be changed.  So all your old, existing commits hold *all* versions of all of your files, as of what was in them when you committed them.  They are frozen for all time—and, to keep them safe like this without taking up too much disk space, they're in a special, compressed, read-only, Git-only form.

Every commit has a "true name": the raw hash ID.  When you run `git log` you'll see these big ugly hash IDs, or sometimes a trimmed-down version of them.  That raw hash ID will always work to name *that* commit.  Other names—such as `master` or some other branch or tag name—serve to name one particular commit too, but *branch* names move over time: a branch name simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit that should be considered part of that branch.

Because files inside commits are frozen and Git-only, you need a way to *work with* the un-frozen and reconstituted versions of those files.  The way Git lets you work with your own files is that it copies the frozen, compressed, Git-only files—I call these *freeze-dried*—into a work area where your files are restored to their normal format.  Git calls this work area the *work tree*, or sometimes *working tree* or *working directory* or some variant on these names.  ("Working directory" implies just one level of folder so for some years the Git folks have been trying to make it consistently use the phrase "work tree" instead.  I like to hyphenate it sometimes.)

You can get *all* files from *any particular commit* into your work-tree using `git checkout`.  To do that, you can give `git checkout` the raw hash ID of the historical commit.<sup>1</sup>  The problem, of course, is that this checks out the entire commit, *removing* the versions of those files that are from the last commit in whatever branch you're working on, and replacing them with the versions from the old commit.

Hence, as in [knittl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59119978/1256452), you probably want to extract just *one* (or several) files from an old commit, into your work-tree area, so that you can see it and work on/with it.  The `git show` command can show one file from any commit, using `git show hash:path`.  This shows the file's contents to `git show`'s standard output, so you'd need to redirect that output to a new file somewhere on your computer (anywhere, in or outside of your work-tree, will do).

Another way to do this is to create a second work-tree.  Since Git 2.5 (with some big important bug fixes in several versions through Git 2.15),<sup>2</sup> Git has had a `git worktree` command.  This command can be told to create a *new* work-tree, somewhere outside of your current work-tree.  Git used to have only one work-tree per repository.  Now that Git has the ability to have more than one, we have to call the original one something: I use the word "main" or "primary" here.

To use `git worktree add` to get a *detached HEAD* commit (see footnote 1 again), run `git worktree add path commit-hash`.  For instance, if the old versions of all of your files that you'd *like* to use are in commit `28014c1084`, and `/tmp/foo` is a good place to put them, you could run:

```
$ git worktree add /tmp/foo 28014c1084
```

which would print something like this (depending on Git vintage):

```
Preparing worktree (detached HEAD 28014c1084)
HEAD is now at 28014c1084
```

At this point, a new tree full of files exists in `/tmp/foo`, and those files are *all* the files extracted from commit `28014c1084`.

When you're done with the added work-tree—have copied all the files you care about, out of it—simply *remove* it:

```
$ rm -r /tmp/foo
```

and then use `git worktree prune` to eliminate it from the list of work-trees:

```
$ git worktree list
[path]    d9f6f3b619 [master]
/tmp/foo  28014c1084 (detached HEAD)
$ git worktree prune
$ git worktree list
[path]    d9f6f3b619 [master]
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This produces what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.  That's good for viewing historical commits, and not so good for doing new work.  To get out of this mode, simply `git checkout` any branch name.

<sup>2</sup>If you have a Git version predating 2.15, it's OK to use `git worktree add` as long as you *don't* leave that added work-tree sitting around for too long.  The nastiest bug, fixed in 2.15, is that after two weeks or so, if you work in the main work-tree for two or more weeks while leaving an added work-tree around, the added work-tree's internal objects may be accidentally destroyed in some cases.  So the simple rule of thumb I suggest for anyone with Git 2.5 through 2.14 is: *upgrade if possible; if not, only use an added work-tree for at most a week or so.*

Comment: Thanks! I would definitely do the worktree method if I wanted a copy of multiple old files scattered across different directories. In my situation, I ended up just checking out the old commit, manually copied the files I wanted (all from the same directory) to somewhere outside of the repo, checked back to my working branch, copied the old files into a subdirectory within the repo and committed. I'll accept your answer though because it's more general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git show` to show content of a file at any given commit:

```
git show deadbeef:path/to/file1 > file1.old
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I could achieve this for multiple files at a time?

Comment: Yes, using a loop in your favorite shell